# Qual è il senso di "cascare" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Diceria dell'untore*, di Gesualdo Bufalino, ho letto:

> «Dicono di un capitano delle Esse Esse, di una villa
>   su un lago. E cose peggiori. Certo i capelli le sono ricresciuti da poco sul capo rasato...».
>   
>         Prosit, eccomi fin troppo servito. Due volte intoccabile, un record. Ero **cascato bene** a impressionarmene,
>    io che per quelli dell’altra parte nutrivo fino a ieri, esclusivo come un amore, un livore da ragazzo, al di là di
>   ogni condiscendenza, dubbio o perdono.

Sapreste spiegarmi cosa vuol dire "ero cascato bene" in questo brano? Nel [dizionario De Mauro](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/cascare) ho trovato che "cascare bene" significa "capitare a proposito", ma non mi  sembra che questo sia il senso adatto al testo sopra citato.

Comment: Secondo me nel senso di "_avevo fatto proprio bene (anche se involontariamente) a..._"

Answer (score 1):

Invece secondo me, Il "capitare a proposito" è corretto in questa frase, si intende che "aveva fatto bene" ad impressionarsene, nel momento giusto diciamo.

Comment: "Ero capitato a proposito" a impressionarmene?

Comment: come ho scritto nel mio precedente commento, a me "cascare" qui dà l'idea di un qualcosa che capita in modo involontario...

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Ma è l'io narrante quello che "era cascato".